# convert seconds into days hours minutes seconds in snowflake QUERY

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Convert seconds into days hours minutes seconds in snowflake QUERY

```
Input time in Seconds: 259321
Output time : 3 days, 2 minutes, 1 second
```

Comment: Have you tried math?

Comment: So what have you tried and what issue are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already mentioned, it's just math, more specifically, the beauty of modulo `%`

```
set seconds=291921;
 
select floor($seconds/60/60/24) as days,
       floor($seconds/60/60%24) as hours,
       floor($seconds/60%60) as minutes, 
       floor($seconds%60) as seconds
```